# Apply layout-fill only in landscape mode Angular material

Tags: angular-material

I have two divs inside a md-content, I want to apply layout fill for the first div only in landscape mode. Is there a way to handle it.

```
<md-content layout-fill layout="column" flex >
      <div flex="45" id="c1" layout layout-align="center center"> 
        <div>
          <img src="http://www.hdicon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/visa_2014-100x100.png" width="100" height="100"><br>
          <span>Label</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div flex="55" id="c2" layout layout-align="center center"> 
        <div>
          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>First name</label>
            <input name="name" ng-model="user.name" required>                            
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>     
  </md-content>
```

http://codepen.io/ankamsarav/pen/KzrPNX

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to conditionally apply this directive. To work around this, you could instead have two `<md-content></md-content>` directives and use an `ng-if` to toggle them such that only one is rendered into the DOM at a time.

```
<md-content layout-fill ng-if="landscapeBoolean">...</md-content>
<md-content ng-if="!landscapeBoolean">...</md-content>
```

You could then listen for the orientation change event and toggle your boolean accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but we have to duplicate the entire content for one attribute :(

Comment: Yeah, its not the most satisfying solution but I don't think there is a better way. You could define a directive for the inner contents, so there wouldn't need to be much duplication.  Since ng-if only renders if the if condition is met, the directive would only get rendered once on page load.